# How to cut away the end of a textfile after a specified line

Tags: text-processing

I have `== Changelog ==` in a textfile and I want to create a new file where this line and everything after it will be deleted.

I am sure the answer is here somewhere, I have tried to search, now my head is spinning. `sed, awk, csplit, ...` ?

Comment: `awk '/Changelog/{exit}1' file > newfile`

Comment: Thanks. I better use `'/== Changelog/{exit}1'` or I get the wrong line by accident or not?

Comment: That all depends on what else is in your input file... Does Changelog appear on another line?

Comment: Maybe, maybe later so I will be specific in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed '/== Changelog ==/,$d' file > newfile
```

This syntax is less efficient than the one proposed above by jasonwryan, but it is more readable by most people. There are two famous use for sed: the basic search and replace `s///` and range based action `/beginpattern/,/endpattern/X` where X is a sed action like **d**elete, **s**earch-replace... Any construction with a semicolon (;) is more programmatic and less understood.

Comment: Accepted for putting the `==` in there. And because `sed` `,$d` is quite easy to remember for me. Its actually almost impossible that there is another capital case `Changelog` in there but still I like it this way more. But for to include just the == before the word so I can forget the == after the words. I did that once. Its about https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt btw. In this annoying light markdown hears closing are actually not optional like in real markdown.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk '/Changelog/{exit}1' file > newfile
```

or with sed:

```
sed -n '/Changelog/q;p' file > newfile
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer ignore the `==` signs?

Comment: @Lohoris Yes, see the comments under the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
csplit -f newfile -n1 infile /==\ Changelog\ ==/
```

That will create `./newfile0` and `./newfile1` *(w/ GNU `csplit`, or POSIXly `./newfile[12]`)*. The first will contain all lines up to the first occurring line that matches `== Changelog ==` and the second will contain all lines following that.